# How do I convert date-time to date in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`20170302092100` should be `2017-03-02`.

Have used this formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),RIGHT(B2,2))
```

but it is getting the result as `2/28/2017`.
`YYYY` and `MM` is correct, not sure why date is incorrect and where is `28` coming from.

Comment: replace `RIGHT(B2,2)` with `MID(B2,7,2)`

Answer (score 3):

Your `"RIGHT(B2,2)"` formula is getting the last 2 digits of your DateTime, so:

201703020921**00**

Running your `"LEFT()"`, `"RIGHT()"` AND `"MID()"`, you get: **2017 3 0**

And when you put that into a formula `=Date(2017,3,0)` you'll get 2/28/2017

The correct formula would be: `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is:

`=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))`